# Can I create Wifi hotspot from within virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Ubunutu 14.04 within VirtualBox on a Windows 8.1 host. I need to test Ubuntu's ability to share it's internet connection and create a WiFi hotspot, is this possible within this setup?

The host computer has an Ethernet and WiFi cards.

Comment: A guest VM could possibly be able to create a wifi hotspot in the VM, but it can't do that on the host so it is not relevant whether the host has Wifi card or not (unless you are asking if a guest VM can create a hotspot in the host, for which the answer is a no). Virtualisation by definition requires separation of the host environment from the guest, and for a guest to be able to produce new network configurations in the host would be a severe security breach.

Comment: Thank you, and that does make sense. Would this be possible using an USB Wi-Fi dongle? In theory could Virtual  mount the USB and use its Wi-Fi capabilities?

Comment: I don't know if that is possible to do. I've been under impression that mounting only applies to file storage, not any other functions.

Comment: Ok, I'll give a try and report back on how I get on. Thank you for your help, it certainly stopped me from banging my head against a wall for a few days!

Comment: As a update, it is possible to create a Wi-Fi hotpost within a virtual box VM by using an external USB dongle. This method allows the VM to create Wi-Fi hotspot which can share the internet connection of the host.

Comment: Great that you could figure that out! You should be able to add that as an answer now to this question, which could serve other people wondering the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an update, it is possible to create a Wi-Fi hotspot within a virtual box VM by using an external USB dongle. This method allows the VM to create a Wi-Fi hotspot that can share the host's internet connection.

Useful information about creating a Wi-Fi hotspot can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490950/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu).